Run a class function with a string input
I am converting a program from one database (SQL Lite) to Mongo DB: so I have tons of functions that im trying to simplify.
How do I run a class function with the text input?
Example
def getListData(DataTableName: str) -> dict:

    tempData = class.DataTableName()

    print(tempData)

and example of the function that would be called is this in the class:
`
 def Breeds(self) -> dict:
        self.convertSQLtoDict(sqlTable="Breeds")
        return self.result

the above will return a dict that was converted from one of the sql tables
So ideally I would like to run
getListData(DataTableName: str = "Breeds")

and this will the function and then also
tempData = class.Breeds() 

(Breeds substituted from the DataTableName)

You can use pythons “getattr()” function to call a method of a class based on the string input.

with this I get a bound method error

@CoenraadPrinsloo there is no such thing as a "bound method error", no doubt, you are getting some other error where the message include the words "bound method". In any case, you need to provide exactly what you've done, because using getattr is the normal solution to this problem (retrieving an  attribute from an object using a str)

you can use __getattribute__ method from the class to set behaviour of the missing class attributes/methods.
class ConverterProto():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __getattribute__(self, table_name):
        func = lambda : print("data from", table_name)
        return func


_class = ConverterProto()
_class.Breeds()


# or now you can call gettattr
new_func = getattr(_class, 'Breeds')
new_func()

In your case if you want to have everything in one class maybe you need to consider smth like this:
from typing import Callable


   
class ConverterProto():

    def convertSQLtoDict(self, sqlTable:str) -> dict:
        print("converting table")
        return {'data': [0,1,2,3,4]}
        
    def __getattr__(self, table_name:str) -> -> Callable[[], dict]:

        # assume that table name should start with upper case
        # for example "Breeds", "Movies" and etc
        if not table_name[0].isupper():
            return None

        # you need to return function (Callable object)                        
        func = lambda: self.convertSQLtoDict(table_name)
        return func


_class = ConverterProto()
_class.Breeds()
_class.Movies()
_class.Actors()


I don't think you understood the situation. They want to define a function, def getListData(DataTableName: str) -> dict: that does this. Presumably, they cannot modify the class that they are a client of.

I understand and agree with your point. Most probably I didn't give the full answer, however partly it is because the initial question is very vague. I don't think that it is clear what is the sequence of function calls. But back to your point: the author didn't say that he can't modify the class. My guess that you can at least create a class that inherits original class. Second, from my understanding def getListData is an entry point to class call _class.Actors() which then returns dict. Thus my advise might be useful. But I am open to any other interpretations.
